# VSCodeでターミナルが表示できない

Tags: vscode

以下の環境にて、タブで「ターミナル」→「新しいターミナル」をクリックすると、一瞬下の方にターミナルの枠が表示されるのですが、すぐに消えてしまいます。

VSCodeは公式サイトからダウンロードしました。
また、一度アンインストールして再インストールしました。
これからいろいろやっていきたいので、ぜひともVSCodeでターミナルを使いたいのです。
解決方法を教えて下さい。

M1MacBookAir

バージョン: 1.75.1 (Universal)
コミット: 441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf
日付: 2023-02-08T21:34:59.000Z
Electron: 19.1.9
Chromium: 102.0.5005.194
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.2.0
Sandboxed: No

Comment: VS Code でなくて普通にターミナルを開いたときに正常に開けますか？　~/.zshenv など起動時に評価されるファイルにエラーが含まれている可能性について考えています。

Comment: 普通のターミナルは正常に動いています。

Comment: さきほど、ChatGPTに聞いたら、以下の解答を得、２番のもので、今のところターミナルが表示されるようになりました。ありがとうございました。「（１）VS Codeを再起動してみてください。問題が解決するかもしれません。
（２）VS Codeの設定で、デフォルトのシェルが正しいかどうかを確認してください。ターミナルを開いたときに起動するシェルを設定する必要があります。設定の「terminal.integrated.shell.osx」を「/bin/bash」に設定してみてください。
（３）VS Codeのログを確認して、問題が何であるかを特定してください。[「アクティビティバー」>「表示」>「出力」]をクリックして、ログを表示します。
（４）VS Codeのアンインストールと再インストールを試してみてください。
（５）他のターミナルエミュレータアプリケーションを使用してみてください。例えば、iTerm2、Hyper、またはTerminatorなどがあります。
これらの手順を試しても解決しない場合、問題が何であるかを特定するために詳細な診断が必要になるかもしれません。」

Comment: M1 Mac で特に設定を変更していないのであれば、ターミナルでは bash ではなくて zsh を利用されていませんか。

Comment: はい、今確認したらzshでした。→（２）にするとよくないいですか？

Comment: よくないとまでは言いませんが、ターミナルアプリと VS Code の terminal とでシェルが違うと混乱するかと思います。たとえば（２）の方法で /bin/zsh にすると正常に開けるようになるなら、そちらの方が良いです。